# Nginx rewrite with question mark

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite this url (yes, the url has a question mark): `domain.com/blog/blogdetail?id=20`

to this: `domain.com/train/my-page`

This is what I have currently, but it's not working:

```
location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog/blogdetail(.*)id=20$ $scheme://$host/train/my-page permanent; 
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. I have tried with `location /blog/` and escaping the /'s in the regex.

Any ideas what I'm missing or another way to go about this? Basically I have a bunch of pages with specific id #'s that I need to rewrite to their respective "word-based" urls.

Comment: Tell whats your expected output.

Comment: Nginx rewrites only "path" part of uri without query.

Comment: @depsai My expected output is the very first part of the question.

Comment: @AlexeyTen sorry I don't understand...

Comment: rewrite process only '/blog/blogdetail' part.

Comment: @AlexeyTen shoot. any ideas on how to get it to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong logic here, it should be a clean URL rewritten to some fancy internal one, not the opposite. Also you should have a clean relationship between both.

Anyway, nginx doesn't match arguments in most of its directives, including location and rewrite. The cleaner way to do this is via the [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) directive.

```
map $request_uri $target_uri {
    "~/blog/blogdetail\?id=20$" "/train/my-page";
}

server {

    ...

    location /blog {
        rewrite ^/blog/blogdetail$ $scheme://$host$target_uri? permanent;
    }

}
```